# The following error occurred while executing this line:

Tags: java

I have this error where I build and clean my project :

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Application-d'eau -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Application-d'eau\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Application-d'eau\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Application-d'eau\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Application-d'eau\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Application-d'eau\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Application-d'eau\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Application-d'eau\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 5 source files to C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Application-d'eau\build\classes
javac: invalid flag: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Application-d
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Application-d'eau\nbproject\build-impl.xml:930: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Application-d'eau\nbproject\build-impl.xml:270: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Comment: Maybe you can quote (with double quotes) your parameter, but even better is not to put spaces, separators, special characters in project names, paths etc ...

Comment: thank you for your answer , could you be more specifiec ; so we could solve this problem   , thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Netbeans, but from what I read NB uses ant for builds.

Ant task fails because you have a single quote in your project name, and the project name is not wrapped in double quotes.

You could rename your project into somethink without quotes or spaces like: `application_d_eau`.

Comment: thanks the problem resolu i change the name of project

Comment: HI. i build and clean my project  avec successful but i have this error in consol of netbeans  ::::::  Note: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Applicationeau\src\timjichte\Authentifier.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.